# PayPal IPN settings

Tags: paypal-ipn, zapier

I have been looking for this everywhere and cannot seem to find it. May I have more than one IPN? I only ask because right now, the ipn is setup to work with my membership site Kajabi. But I want to add the Zapier IPN to PayPal so that I can do more with my paying clients. It works super well with Stripe but it looks like I would have to remove my current IPN to add zapier hooks.

Could really use your feedback.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you can create multiple IPN's for a single PayPal account. You may have to consider using [the REST API to create webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-webhook) (you can have up to 10 different webhooks).